# isomorphism between subset of SU(2) and SO(3)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, quaternions

I know that there is a  surjective map $\Phi : SU(2)\to SO(3)  $.

My question is if there is a subgroup $A \subset SU(2)$ such that $\Phi_{|A}:A\to SO(3)$ can be a (group) isomorphism.

What would $A$ be?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such a subgroup $A\subset\operatorname{SU}(2)$ fails to exist on topological grounds; I'll assume it to be known that $\operatorname{SU}(2)\cong S_3$ and $\operatorname{SO}(3)\cong\Bbb{RP}^3$. The usual surjective map 
$$\Phi:\ \operatorname{SU}(2)\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{SO}(3)$$
is a homomorphism of topological groups, hence its restriction to $A$ is a homeomorphism. This implies that $S_3$ contains a subspace homeomorphic to $\Bbb{RP}^3$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much @Servaes

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If there were such a subgroup $A$, then for any $g \in SU(2) - A$, $A \cup gA$ would be a separation of $SU(2)$---but $SU(2)$ is connected.

Comment: +1 I guess this implicitly uses the fact that $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ is also connected?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the proof goes through without needing that fact, I think. In any case, that fact follows immediately from the connectedness of $SU(2)$ and the continuity of $\Phi : SU(2) \to SO(3)$.